# QComboBox emit signal when an option is picked PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I'm currently making an application and I stumbled upon a problem, I want to make a QCombobox emit a signal whenever the user picked and option in the combo box so I made this code:

```
    self.payrollMonths = ['August', 'July']
    self.payrollmonthCombo = QComboBox()
    self.payrollmonthCombo.addItems(self.payrollMonths)
    self.payrollmonthCombo.currentTextChanged().connect(foo())
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the problem? The relevant signals are all clearly documented: [QComboBox Signals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#signals).

Comment: @ekhumoro well you see when I run that code I get always this error: native Qt signal is not callable

Comment: Oh - it's just a typo. Use: `self.payrollmonthCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(foo) `.

Comment: well I tried this `self.payrollmonthCombo.currentTextChanged().connect(self.setuPayrolltable)` I still get the error I also initialized the `@pyqtSlot()` but seemed does nothing to solve it

Comment: That's because you didn't use the code I gave you. Don't add parentheses to the signal (because as the error-message tells you, it's not callable).

Comment: See: [PyQt5 Signals and Slots](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html).